# How to rename variables that have similar names and code in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind, sqldf

I have a list in csv format of different names with the same underlying code below:

```
Code       Name

25000      James John Junior

RA25000    James Junior

RA2500009  James J. Junior

RA27000       Bill Hope

RA2800009   Donna Scott

28000            Donna Love Scott
```

Since the list shares the same underlying code 25000 and 28000, how can I change the list to have the same name James John Junior, the name associated with 25000, and Donna Love Scott, the name associated with 28000, as shown below (in R):

```
Code       Name

25000          James John Junior

RA25000       James John Junior

RA2500009  James John Junior

RA27000       Bill Hope

RA2800009   Donna Love Scott

28000            Donna Love Scott
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple cases we can do something like this instead, using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df$Name <- case_when(
  grepl("25000", df$Name) ~ "James John Junior",
  grepl("28000", df$Name) ~ "Donna Love Scott",
  grepl("27000", df$Name) ~ "Bill Hope",
  TRUE ~ df$Name
)
```

Comment: As long as the pattern "25000" doesn't appear for any other names, this strategy should still work regardless of the size of the data

Comment: Only The pattern of it being 5 digits is the same (like 25000 and 28000)